# Display: Block link is taking more width in firefox browser vs google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, sass

Display: block is taking more width in firefox, please find the code below

```
<ul class="mn_mainNav">
<li><a href="#">All Offers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">All Offers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">All Offers</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
.mn_mainNav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;

    & > li {
      & > a {
        display: block;
   text-transform: lowercase;

        &:first-letter {
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/snehav27/0w5Lfz1n/)

Chrome:
[image]

vs firefox:

[image]

Any pointer will be appreciated

Note: I do need the first letter for the li link to be upper case

Comment: Really strange and never see that before. You can fix that using `display: inline` but it doesn't explain the problem :/

Comment: a Firefox bug I suppose. Not that you have shared the same screenshot twice

Comment: They look the same for me in  both browsers, how do you compare them?

Comment: a reduced version of the code that still produce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/y7jfs1cm/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you will replace

Comment: @Grumpy updated the images and  check the link now

Comment: @johannchopin not I cant make the first letter uppercase if I use inline is there any other alternative

Comment: It will also uppercase if you use inline-block, but firefox has the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in firefox when using `::first-letter`, so I would just try and use `text-transform: capitalize` on the `a` tag instead.  This will of course capitalize every word not just the first, but if you don't mind that, then this will work for you.

```css
.mn_mainNav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.mn_mainNav>li>a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mn_mainNav">
  <li><a href="#">All Offers</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">All Offers</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">all offers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for update But I want it to work as "All offers" O as small letter. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/snehav27/0w5Lfz1n/5/

```
<ul class="mn_mainNav">
<li><a class="mn_repaintHack" href="#">All Offers</a></li>
<li><a class="mn_repaintHack" href="#">All Offers</a></li>
<li><a class="mn_repaintHack" href="#">All Offers</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
@-moz-keyframes repaintHack {
  from { padding-right: 1px; }
  to { padding-right: 0; }
}

.mn_mainNav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;

    & > li {
      & > a {
        display: block;
        text-transform: lowercase;

        &:first-letter {
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }

         &.mn_repaintHack {
          animation: repaintHack 0.00000001s;
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

I just tried to repaint the screen after load so it tried to load the UI properly.
Works well in firefox now.

Note: This solution was found by reading other posts in stackoverflow.